# Spring Cloud Contract support for Node JS?

Tags: node.js, spring-cloud-contract

Is there a Verifier equivalent on the JS Node side? Is it possible to write Rest API test in JS Node that can access the stubs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently we don't support the tests generation out of the box. However since sc contract is pluggable (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/spring-cloud-contract.html#_pluggable_architecture) there's no problem to write a test generator that will generate a node js test. If that's not acceptable for you you can check out Pact and use their api. SC contract also understands Pact files as contract definition.

As for using stubs you can use the Stun Runner Boot application to download and start stubs that your node js application can use (example https://github.com/marcingrzejszczak/sc-contract-car-rental/blob/master/README.adoc#stub-runner-boot-with-a-nodejs-ap)

Comment: Marcin,  thanks for the quick response. Sorry I meant StubRunner instead of Verifier. Our  java monolithic app has been broken down into micro-services (about over a hundred of them by now) and several services talk to each other. We decided to use Spring Cloud since our services all run in Java and we rely heavily on Spring. But we have a few clients in JS Node that we will need to write consumer tests for. So I assume the Stub Runner Boot  like you mentioned is the equivalent in JS Node? Also, is this the best way to reach you?

Comment: Yeah stub runner is the way. Yesterday I've added support for stubrunner in sitting cloud CLI (http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-cli/spring-cloud-cli.html) so it should be even easier for you. The best way to reach me is via gitter https://gitter.im/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract . If you think that I've managed to answer your question let's Mark it as answered :)

Comment: Marked answered. Thanks Marcin.

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak this was answered back in 2017, has anything been implemented since to support this?

Comment: Yeah we have the polyglot support https://spring.io/blog/2018/02/13/spring-cloud-contract-in-a-polyglot-world and https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/docker-project.html#docker-how-it-works