# What are some methods to document contracts between microservices?

Tags: rest, microservices, distributed, api-design

In an HTTP-driven microservices architecture, each service might have a number of public endpoints that return JSON, for example, to a client or an API gateway intermediary. These services could also accept POSTs with JSON bodies of a certain shape, or query strings of a certain shape, etc.

What are some good options for documenting or programmatically keeping track of these "contracts" between services? I.e, if service A's `/getThing` endpoint has been refactored to return different data, is there a documentation tool or methodology that would facilitate updating the API gateway to adapt to this change?

Answer (score 2):

For programmatically management of **contracts**, if you using spring-cloud stack then you must look into [spring-cloud-contract](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/), by which you can easily keep track of your latest version of contracts for your Rest endpoints and also if any change occurs in your api endpoint, this will help you notify by breaking the contract and failing the test-cases build around it.

Let's say for example, service A's `/getThing` endpoint has been refactored to return different data then all calling services to this endpoint will fail while build time of your project.

However, this methodology won't facilitate updating the API gateway to adapt to this change as there might different logic you want to perform of every new version of your endpoints.

You can also create Rest Docs snippets using these endpoint contracts. checkout [Rest Docs snippets](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/single/spring-cloud-contract.html#_generating_spring_rest_docs_snippets_from_the_contracts). You can also use [swagger](https://swagger.io/) for documenting your endpoints.

for NodeJs check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828892/spring-cloud-contract-support-for-node-js).